# How do I keep/blur TextInput keyboard on React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I tap on textinput and the keyboard slide from the bottom, how do I slides it back down or keep/blur the keyboard on react native?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Utilities/dismissKeyboard.js

```
var dismissKeyboard = require('dismissKeyboard')

onPressCancelButton {
    dismissKeyboard();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use iqkeyboardManager best for hide keyboard with done button toolbar

Link: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Keyboard` module from `react-native`.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard

`import { Keyboard } from react-native;`

`Keyboard.dismiss();`

Answer (score -1):

This is the default behavior right now. Show `onFocus` and hide `onBlur`. So no need for an extra library anymore.